# Can't show my array data in my application using angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a little problem, so I will write my code first, and try to explain what I want to achieve later, here is my class PostComponent :

```
 export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('data') data;
    @Input('comments') comments = [
         {
            text:"data"
         }
   ]

   constructor(){}
   ngOnInit(){}

 }
```

And here is my post.component.html :

```
<div class="data">
   <h2>{{data}}</h2>
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let coment of comments">
        {{coment.text}}
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is my AppComponent.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent {
   posts = [
     { 
       data:"data1",
       comments:[
         {
            text: 'text1' 
         },
         {
            text: 'text2' 
         }
       ]
      },
      { 
       data:"data2",
       comments:[
         {
            text: 'text3' 
         },
         {
            text: 'text5' 
         }
       ]
      }

   constructor(){}

   }
```

And that is my app.component.html :

```
  <div *ngFor="let post of posts" >
     // the value of the selector is post instead of app-post
     <post [data]="post.data" [comments]="post.comments" >
     </post> 
  </div>
```

And this is What I want to get :

```
 data1 

 text1 
 text2


 data2 

 text3
 text5
```

But I am getting the error in my console :

```
ng:///AppModule/PostComponent.ngfactory.js:105 ERROR Error: Cannot find a 
differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only 
supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I hope you understood my problem, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your component selector

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-post', 
})
```

// if u are using post so u need to change it to

```
 @Component({
        selector: 'post', 
 })
```

Comment: Well it is, I mentionned that in a comment .. Thank you sir .. I edited my post I have an other error if you want to help.

Answer (score 0):

make your posts to

```
posts = [
    { 
       data:"data1",
       comments:[
         {
            text: 'text1' 
         },
         {
            text: 'text2' 
         }
       ]
      },
      { 
       data:"data2",
       comments:[
         {
            text: 'text3' 
         },
         {
            text: 'text5' 
         }
       ]
}]



<div *ngFor="let post of posts" >
     // the value of the selector is post instead of app-post
     <post [data]="post.data" [comments]="post.comments" >
     </post> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, It worked, not your proposition that worked but thanks anyway Sir for your precious time, have a nice day.

Comment: that's great to hear you solve your issue by your self. happy coding brother.